# how to use custom font in phone gap?

Tags: android, cordova

I'm using phonegap to build android application and I face some problem.

```
<style type="text/css">
@font-face{
    font-family: customfont;
    src: url("fonts/THSarabunNew.ttf") format('truetype');

}
body {
    font-family: customfont;
    font-size:30px;
}
</style>
```

I try to use this code in **index.html** file but I cannot use my custom font in application.

please tell me a way to use custom font in phonegap on android app.

thanks

Comment: It'll work, I think some style is overwriting the body's css

Comment: It's not working for me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
        @font-face {
            font-family: centurySchoolbook;
            src: url(/fonts/century-schoolbook.ttf);
        }
       body {
           font-family: centurySchoolbook;
           font-size:30px;
       }
</style>
```

If your font still doesn't work, make sure you're spelling its typeface name and its file name correctly, your app caches are behaving, your mobile OS isn't messing around with a font. check the css overwriting things first.